# Google Chrome Cherokee Unicode Boxes/Squares

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, unicode

My Software I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and  Google Chrome 64-bit Version 57.0.2987.98

When I bring up Google Chrome and type inside the URL using Cherokee keyboard I am able to see "ᏣᎳᎩ" Which shows letters similar to "GWY" in Cherokee script upon pressing enter my entire webpage is written in small little boxes. I am able to type like normal in the program notepad, wordpad, and Skype with no issues. 
My issue first started back in August of 2016 and no one was able to help me on Google's Product forums, I'm really running out of options here. If my thread is against the rules let me know. :( 
I'll really appreciate it if anyone can please help me solve this. :(

I also have two pictures but I'll hold back from posting them in case they're against the rules.

### Chrome + Firefox pictures below

[image: Web Browser Picture]

[image: Firefox Example]

Edit2: I should also add that if I highlight those "boxes" It'll show text such as "ᏣᎳᎩ" or "ᎣᏏᏲ" or "ᏩᏙ" in the area where it says search google for "...." So how come I can't actually see it when I type it? but yet I can see it if I highlight it? This doesn't make any sense. :(

Comment: Images are fine and might be helpful - just throw in on imgur. It does feel like a font/keyboard issue

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We are always glad to help, but please don't put "**Solved**" in the title of your question.  Within our community, the fact that you designated an answer as the official solution already shows us that the problem has been solved.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's what you have to do :

1. Download [Code2000 Font Set](http://gschoppe.com/projects/fbformat/includes/unicodefont.zip)
2. Install all the three ttf files.
3. Restart Chrome ( Also try rebooting PC if it doesn't work)

Credits : [gschoppe](http://gschoppe.com/uncategorized/fixing-unicode-support-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: Thank you so much. ᏩᏙ. It's been 8 months since I've been able to read the script. I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: you're ᎤᎵᎮᎵᏍᏗ :)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your keyboard language is properly set. To do so follow steps provided in this [post](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12578/add-keyboard-languages-to-xp-vista-and-windows-7/) (Go under Keyboard if you don't find your language)

Secondly,install google input tools extension from chrome web store and add your language under "selected input tools".

Also [try this](http://www.tavultesoft.com/keyman/downloads/keyboards/search.php?Search=cherokee&Submit=Search&btnsubmit.x=0&btnsubmit.y=0) and let me know.

Have you tried typing it on other browsers like Firefox or IE ?

Comment: The keyboard is correctly installed under Regions & Languages as I have other keyboards enabled as well. I installed google input tools extension, located "Cherokee" and everything was little boxes like always, even used both options for Cherokee. I have the exact keyboard except it was downloaded from Cherokee Nation's website directly, same file size & author as well. I did try to install it but windows told me it's already installed. I can type Cherokee on IE & Firefox, but it's just not the same, it's a little annoying because the font is too small and next to impossible to read.

Comment: did you try increasing the font size?

Comment: Yes I did, it's like it's permanently fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the font chrome is using dosen't quite support cherokee.

Annoyingly, the "simple" way of doing this - [setting per script encoding seems to have been removed](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/-Ul20dPvbbo). Essentially you could try setting unicode fonts to get it to work, or set a per script encoding and font.

There's no way for me to check if it works (the cherokee wiki seems to have appropriate symbols I am illiterate in) - but `chrome://settings/fonts` has an advanced font settings option, that points at a [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-font-settings/caclkomlalccbpcdllchkeecicepbmbm) to set per script font settings.

[image]

Go there, pick a font you know works and test.

Comment: I went to the font settings, changed script to something I can read, changed the fonts to Digohweli Tsalagi. Clicked on save. Opened a new tab proceeded to type "ᏣᎳᎩ" and got three little boxes. I'm starting to lose hope. :(

Comment: Hm. It works for me on chrome canary. Setting that is not a proper answer, but it can be a temporary workaround. Give that a shot

Comment: I actually gave Chrome Canary a try 2 days ago and it didn't work for me. I can try  it again.

Comment: Ok I downloaded & installed Chrome canary (Gold icon) I typed ᏣᎳᎩ  and I got the same results as I do in Google Chrome. 
[Chrome Canary](http://i.imgur.com/ZCK7r5a.png) <--